# 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'case'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm getting an error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'case'

Does anyone see what I have written wrong? This is T-SQL.

```
SELECT 
    @ifAtOffice     
    CASE
       WHEN @ifAtOffice = 1  
          THEN 'Device is still assigned to a client, locate is at Office' AS description, 2 AS resultCode, 
       WHEN @ifAtOffice = 0 
          THEN 'Device is still assigned to a client, locate is not at Office' AS description, 3 AS resultCode, 
    END
```

Comment: remove @ifAtOffice from before case or put a comma after it

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'case'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'. (Line 148)

Comment: result from removing @ifAtOffice

Comment: `CASE` in T-SQL is an **expression** (just like `a+b`) which can return **one, single atomic value** - you cannot return several bits of information in each `WHEN` branch......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

actually you have quite a few issues.  Here is a solution:

```
DECLARE @ifAtOffice AS BIT

SET @ifAtOffice = 1

SELECT @ifAtOffice,
     case 
       when @ifAtOffice = 1 then  'Device is still assigned to a client, locate is at Office'       
       when @ifAtOffice = 0 then  'Device is still assigned to a client, locate is not at Office'   
     END AS description, 
     case 
       when @ifAtOffice = 1 then  2 
       when @ifAtOffice = 0 then  3
     END AS resultCode
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Declare   @ifAtOffice int ;

      set @ifAtOffice = 1;

    SELECT 
    @ifAtOffice  , 
   ( CASE
       WHEN @ifAtOffice = 1  
         THEN 'Device is still assigned to a client, locate is at Office' 
       WHEN @ifAtOffice = 0 
          THEN 'Device is still assigned to a client, locate is not at Office'  
          End )  AS description,
        (  CASE
       WHEN @ifAtOffice = 1  
         THEN 2 
       WHEN @ifAtOffice = 0 
         Then 3 end ) As resultCode
```